# How to show installed packages for react project?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to list the installed packages for my react project. But when I run

```
npm list -g
```

I get:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── (empty)
```

Even though I am running through VSC terminal and cd'ed into the correct directory...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`npm list -g` shows packages that are installed globally if you want to show installed packages for specific project remove the `-g` flag

Answer (score 0):

First you can do `npm list` (notice the lack of `-g`) to list of installed packages.

You can open `package.json` and see the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` attributes to see the modules installed with `npm` or similar tools.

You can open `node_modules` directory and see everything that is installed in there.

Comment: Also nice, thanks for the options! I accepted the other because it was first, but thanks!